# Struct to CSV data as string without creating CSV file

Tags: csv, go

I have a `struct` which I want to convert into a CSV string. I don't have to write the CSV file. I just need to create the CSV string.

The Go CSV package (https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/) only provides the writing facility.

Here's the `struct`:

```
type myData struct {
    A string `json:"a"`
    B string `json:"b"`
    C string `json:"c"`
}
```

CSV:

```
1,2,3
4, ,6
```

I wanted a CSV string so that I can directly upload the string as a file in cloud storage via a serverless environment. So, I want to avoid creating a file in serverless environment.

Is there any package that can help in doing this?

Comment: encoding/csv does what you need. Your assumption that encoding/csv allways  creates files is plain  wrong.

Comment: Btw: Asking for third party libraries is OT on SO.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `bytes.Buffer` to write CSV data and get the string like this ([live](https://play.golang.org/p/KoUYE0WzvEW)):

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    pairs := [][]string{
        {"k1", "v1"},
        {"k2", "v2"},
    }

    b := new(bytes.Buffer)
    w := csv.NewWriter(b)

    w.WriteAll(pairs)

    if err := w.Error(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    s := b.String()

    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `bytes.Buffer` to write data without creating file.
With `bytes.Buffer` we can write bytes into a single buffer, and then convert to a string when we are done by invoke the `String()` func.

```golang
var csvData = [][]string{
      {"SuperHero Name", "Power", "Weakness"},
      {"Batman", "Wealth", "Human"},
      {"Superman", "Strength", "Kryptonite"},
   }
buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
wr := csv.NewWriter(buf)
w.WriteAll(csvData)
csvString := buf.String()
```